# Can't mount or get into my /home Drive

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

My system, I run Samsung SSD for the system and I have a 2TB WD HDD for my home drive that is mounted in the /etc/fstab file.

About a week ago my computer (Ubuntu 18.04) went into emergency mode for some reason. I had to run e2fsck on the drive (/dev/sdb1). It fixed the issue and I could boot into my system. I ran SMART util on the WD HDD and it passed with no issues. So I didn't worry about the drive, but for some reason efi, home, and filesystem where mounted in nautilus as if I remounted them and it would not auto recognize dvds, cds, or usbs that I put into the system.

So I decided to reinstall Ubuntu on the SSD and start fresh since I originally started with 16.04 on this system and on upgrades I just did it through the system and not fresh installs. I reinstalled Ubuntu (20.04), but when I ran blkid to see my /dev/sdb drive to put in my /etc/fstab file it is showing /dev/sdb: PTUUID="fdb53124" PTTYPE="dos". When I put this drive in the /etc/fstab it was a UUID and it won't mount and it doesn't find and partitions. I tried running e2fsck and dumpe2fs commands, but nothing. I have a lot of stuff on that drive and I did backup some stuff, but there is a lot I didn't, since SMART told me it was good.

I have not found any other solutions to fix the issue, besides ddrescue, but the last time I used that it copied everything over with the name of the block id or something like that. Any insight will be grateful.

[image]

Comment: Looks like there is a problem with that HDD, cable or something related after all.

Comment: Edit your question and show me a screenshot of `gparted` and /dev/sdb. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema I have added the screenshot of gparted for the /dev/sdb drive.

Comment: Your drive has an (incorrect) MBR partition table, and the drive is empty.

Comment: @heynnema gdisk states that it "Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format in memory". But the I have a lot of stuff still on that drive and I didn't do anything to it. is there a way to fix the MBR table

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to recover. Maybe somebody knows of a sure-fire way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get all my data back. So for anyone that runs into a problem where your drive suddenly losses it's partition and unable to mount testdisk is an easy and powerful tool for recovery.

Pretty easy, just run testdisk select the drive you want to recover, have it analyze your drive, list the contents, and select files to copy, and copy them to another device.