# Whenever I start my laptop it shows many lines of code

Tags: boot, command-line, grub2, hardware, bootloader

Whenever I boot Ubuntu it shows many lines of code. I don't know if those are errors or not, but the system takes a little bit more time to start.

This is what I see:

[image]

[image]

Should I be worried about it or is it normal?

Edited:-
Used this command :-

```
sudo badblocks -v /dev/sda1 > /tmp/bad-blocks.txt
```

And result shows 0 bad blocks found. So now can i rest in peace?

[image: take a look]

Comment: If you can use the system, nothing to worry about.

Comment: Does your system boot at all? Based on the output seen, your disk appears to be dying.

Comment: please don't post images of text. Please replace it by a copy/paste of text so we it is searchable and we can copy/paste it.   (`sudo dmesg`)

Comment: The badcrc notice could be a faulty cable or  an inadequate power supply

Comment: Yes the laptop do boot up and runs fine. And i also conducted some hardrive test using gsmartool and it says "disk is fine"

Comment: IO errors are usually signs of TROUBLE with your hardware, we have no clues as to what Ubuntu product/release you're using, what device SDA is, nor anything about what *file-system* is involved (in those areas of the disk) nor what hardware you're actually using, but I'd explore the issues BEFORE it gets worse, at worst you're only doing some preventative exploration about your *unknown* system as what you show could be warning sign of big problems starting to occur.

Comment: Im using ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. Should i reinstall the ubuntu ?

Comment: You've provided no *file-system* details, and the error shows on **device sda** and not partition 1 (sda1), thus we have no clues as to if you scanned the correct location of device SDA with your SDA1 *badblocks* search. I would **not** re-install the OS, but find out what the error is, and try and be precise; 22.04.3 doesn't tell us if Server, Desktop etc.. I mentioned *file-system* in prior comment, we can't view your *file system table* as we're limited to only the details you provide. I'd work out what the issue is first (using *live* media so you're not using SDA until known)

Comment: I am using dell latitude 7490. Initially it wasnt showing any these ata 3.0 {drdy} its been about 2-3 days but system runs completely fine. As you have mentioned, and laptop has ssd not hdd so cable error would not be there. Sorry but can you please tell me how and what details i can provide you?

Comment: I always change my grub settings to make sure to see those lines. But now faster drives they go by very quickly. Do you have in `cat  /etc/default/grub` the "quiet splash" setting on This line. I change to noplymouth to speed boot a bit but default is quiet splash.  `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="noplymouth" ` Showing boot process does not slow boot much, as it also is being copied into log file. You normally just see logos.
`

Comment: @oldfred yep "quiet splash" is set by default

Comment: @guiverc i again run the test but now as /dev/sda and it took more time to complete and results shows "pass completed 0 bad blocks found" so it means ssd dont have any bad sector at all?

Comment: Have you run e2fsck on sda2, which it looks like is your ext4 partition? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1474846/fixing-bad-superblock-on-ssd-drive-is-e2fsck-safe-to-run

Comment: Being an SSD, the hardware itself may have removed those *badblocks*.  SSDs have a *spare* capacity that gets used when areas go bad, thus they *recovery* after partial failure though SSD capacity will reduce as more recoveries take place (*and spare capacity is exhausted*). Your messages mention specific sectors that the issue occurred with, and after the SSD has re-allocated those *bad blocks* I'd not expect to see those messages  (*every write can destroyed SSD blocks; which is why there is hidden capacity by design to deal with it awhile*)

Comment: @guiverc btw the laptop is running fine and there are bad blocks as you have said those might have been removed by the SSD itself. But I do tired searching for the answers but didn't reach to any conclusion at all. The laptop is running fine and yep it shows some code and then start normally

Answer (score 1):

> The error has been solved and the thing I did was to again install Ubuntu and erase the disk. The boot up is now faster than usual. So, the problem started happening to me when I updated the Dell firmware.
>
> Thank you guys for your support

<sup>Answer moved here from [OP's question](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1483793/5).</sup>