# Unresponsive storage ssd

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, filesystem, ssd

I have a **ssd** with very important data in my workstation.

It has **a ext4 and a ntfs partition.**

This morning, the ext4 partition (sda1) **didn't mount, and the filesystem was listed as "unknown"** in the Disks application. running `file -s /dev/sda1` returns "**no read permissions**"; Overall assessment is marked as "Disk is OK, one bad sector", but attempting to perform any **smart self-test returns the error "sk_disk_open: input/output error (udisks-error-quark, 0)"**.

Now the ntfs partition is also listed as unknown.

Please help. I don't know what to do!

---

Additional info:

The disk is a **Samsung 870 Evo**.

It has important files and a Windows virtual machine that has been glitchy lately.

There was also a power failure recently. Not sure if it's related.

System specs:

```
System:
  Kernel: 6.5.0-21-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A
    Desktop: Cinnamon 5.2.7 tk: GTK 3.24.33 vt: 2 dm: GDM3 42.0
    Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
  Type: Desktop System: MSI product: MS-7885 v: 1.0
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: MSI model: X99A SLI PLUS(MS-7885) v: 1.0
    serial: <superuser required> UEFI-[Legacy]: American Megatrends v: 1.E0
    date: 06/15/2018
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 3.18 TiB used: 1.63 TiB (51.1%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Samsung model: SSD 980 PRO 1TB
    size: 931.51 GiB speed: 63.2 Gb/s lanes: 4 type: SSD serial: <filter>
    rev: 3B2QGXA7 temp: 42.9 C scheme: MBR
  ID-2: /dev/sdb vendor: Western Digital model: WD2003FZEX-00SRLA0
    size: 1.82 TiB speed: 6.0 Gb/s type: HDD rpm: 7200 serial: <filter>
    rev: 1A01 scheme: GPT
  ID-3: /dev/sdc vendor: Samsung model: SSD 860 EVO 500GB size: 465.76 GiB
    speed: 6.0 Gb/s type: SSD serial: <filter> rev: 4B6Q scheme: MBR
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 301.86 GiB used: 137.26 GiB (45.5%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sdc2
  ID-2: /mnt/hdd size: 1.82 TiB used: 1.2 TiB (66.2%) fs: ntfs
    dev: /dev/sdb2
  ID-3: /mnt/mint size: 795.67 GiB used: 295.74 GiB (37.2%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2
  ID-4: /mnt/nas size: 10.46 TiB used: 7.31 TiB (69.9%) fs: cifs
    dev: /dev/Aether
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: partition size: 30.52 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%)
    priority: -2 dev: /dev/sdc3
```

edit:

```
vapor@neon:~$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sd?
[sudo] password for vapor: 
fdisk: cannot open /dev/sda: No such file or directory


Disk /dev/sdb: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD2003FZEX-0
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 0E6D35B6-9595-4967-A9D4-F0C206EF08D7

Device      Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1      34     262177     262144  128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdb2  264192 3907028991 3906764800  1.8T Microsoft basic data

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.


Disk /dev/sdc: 465.76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 860 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xaea8f6b3

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1  *         2048 268437503 268435456   128G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdc2       268437504 912771071 644333568 307.2G 83 Linux
/dev/sdc3       912773120 976773167  64000048  30.5G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

Comment: Sounds like your SSD is dead. RIP.

Comment: Please run `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sd?` and [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1508500/edit) your question to include this information.

Comment: That might be a dead disk but if it is not the ssd it could also be the connector. "with very important data in my workstation."  that should not be a problem then: you will have backups.

Comment: Thanks for the information, but you replaced "?" with "a". Please run the command exactly like this - `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sd?` and update your question.

Comment: Sadly, according to `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sd?` `/dev/sda` is dead.

Comment: `fdisk: cannot open /dev/sda: No such file or directory` says it all. 

Comment: You run fdisk on a partition, not a drive. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1474846/fixing-bad-superblock-on-ssd-drive-is-e2fsck-safe-to-run