Grub screen when trying to boot Ubuntu
I had this problem in the past. This is the third time I reinstall Ubuntu on my laptop.
Everything works fine but then suddenly(it could be after 1 month or 6 months) my laptop starts  freezing and forces me to force shut down. After that Ubuntu won't start and I'm stuck on GRUB screen.
I ran boot-repair:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/PkjRjS9JpP/
I remember a week ago I had to run fsck when starting Ubuntu but it worked.
I have tried every post about "No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda." Nothing worked.
It's weird because I can use Ubuntu for 6 months and the suddenly "no boot loader".

With UEFI install, which you have, you are not supposed to have an old BIOS boot loader in the MBR. So that is just a message. But issue is your install in sda2. That you had to run fsck before may have indicated an issue. So did you update your backup then and maintain good backups? Have you run a full e2fsck. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1474846/fixing-bad-superblock-on-ssd-drive-is-e2fsck-safe-to-run  You have entire drive as / (root) which is a default install. That default is from years ago with smaller drives or dual boot. Often better then to separate / (root) from /home or data.
