I flashed ubuntu onto a computer and uploaded important pictures and videos to it but a power surge hit and it reverted to before i flashed it
I am new to linux and tried to create a nextcloud server to hold pictures and videos for my mom but after some severe weather and power outages the server I was using reverted back to a messed up version of the install that was running before I reflashed the machine to use it as a nextcloud server. for example I installed Ubuntu Server 20.04.6 but after the surges my machine had a desktop interface without me installing one and the nextcoud server was no longer available. Any help recovering the pictures and videos would be greatly appreciated as well as any advice to keep from experiencing this problem in the future

I cannot imagine how a :"revert back" could happen, but I can see how you might have installed onto a different partition, then the reboot gets the old partition.  Please add to your posting (not in comments) your disk partition/volume group/etc. layout.

You have separate /home and if it is not mounted during boot, it reverts to a new /home inside / with all defaults. So do you have a mount issue with the /home partition? I would first try e2fsck. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1474846/fixing-bad-superblock-on-ssd-drive-is-e2fsck-safe-to-run

It was installed onto a different partition and the old one had boot priority thankyou for your help. @ubfan1

You can answer your own question, and after a bit, accept it, helping others and in the process gaining some reputation points.

It was installed onto a different partition and the old one had boot priority so a reboot form a power surge booted the old OS.
