Ubuntu boot issue - reset wipe hard drive
I purchased a new LENOVO laptop (intel ultra 7 / 32gb ram / 1TB hard drive, came with windows 11). First time in my life I DIRECTLY installed ubuntu desktop 24 fresh as soon as i opened it. As part of initial installation Ubuntu took whole of my harddrive, i created password, logged in with ubuntu password and explored for few days. created virtual machines worked fine for few days. I did a Hard powered off (long press on power button) while Ubuntu was running and after which I keep getting msg
Default Boot missing or boot failed
Insert recovery media and hit any key. Choose boot from usb.
Is there a way to completely wipe out or format harddrive with old corrupt version still there? I anyway dont have any data since its a new laptop. Any step by step would be helpful.
Things I tried:
I tried to put windows install usb drive and start windows 11 install from usb, installation says there is no hard drive (i guess since whole of 1TB is used by ubuntu).
Since im new to linux ubuntu,
i used the same ubuntu usb and temporarily got into it ubuntu@ubuntu terminal, i tried to google to repair boot but nothing worked and when i tried to install it too didnt detect hard drive of 1TB.
I tired boot-repair
I tired gparted usb and that too didnt dectect 1tb.
BIOS says Hard disk not detected. Not sure if SSD got toasted and died due to ubuntu or am i missing something.
Please let me know if im missing something and wondering how to get hard drive space back.
Thanks for your time.

Hard shutdown often corrupts partition. I have an external SSD I use with my Windows and had similar issue. It turned out a second FAT32 partition was corrupted. I booted a live installed and ran sudo dosfsck -t /dev/sdb2 as that was the partition. But I also ran dosfsck on ESP & e2fsck on all ext4 partitions, so that may have been issue. Try running file system repairs. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1474846/fixing-bad-superblock-on-ssd-drive-is-e2fsck-safe-to-run & http://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789

Thanks. I dont have windows at all. Whole hard drive was used for Ubuntu.
I tried above command and got the below msg
fsck.fat 4.2 (2021-01-31)
open: No such file or directory.

My example was sdb2, but that probably is not your ESP or FAT32 partition. And booting live installer may change internal drive from sda to sdb or not. You have to always check drive with sudo fdisk -l to see which is ESP or sudo parted -l to see formats of partition. Also lsblk -f -e 7 where -e 7 excludes loop mounts or the snaps which are not real partitions.
