Ubuntu 24.04.1 not booting up - why if not disk damage?

My PC fails to boot up and I observe the following output on my monitor.
It seems to fail at the lines:
/dev/root: Can't open blockdev
VFS: Cannot open root device "/dev/sda2" or unknown block (0,0): error -6
/dev/sda is the main SSD drive in which the Ubuntu 24.04.1 is stored.
Is the SSD corrupted so that the op sys can't be read into RAM ?
In the hope that it wasn't that I tried to restore (via Timeshift) the previous day's state of the 24.04.1 but it just won't boot up. It seized soon into the boot-up sequence and would go no further.
$ sudo fsck -f /dev/sda2
fsck from util-linux 2.37.2
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
/dev/sda2 is mounted.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.

Is a new reinstall the only option other than a new SSD ?
EDIT
$ sudo fsck -V -C /dev/sda1
fsck from util-linux 2.37.2
[/usr/sbin/fsck.vfat (1) -- /dev/sda1] fsck.vfat /dev/sda1 
fsck.fat 4.2 (2021-01-31)
There are differences between boot sector and its backup.
This is mostly harmless. Differences: (offset:original/backup)
  65:01/00
1) Copy original to backup
2) Copy backup to original
3) No action
[123?q]? 3
Dirty bit is set. Fs was not properly unmounted and some data may be corrupt.
1) Remove dirty bit
2) No action
[12?q]? 1

*** Filesystem was changed ***
The changes have not yet been written, you can still choose to leave the
filesystem unmodified:
1) Write changes
2) Leave filesystem unchanged
[12?q]? 1
/dev/sda1: 26 files, 5341/130812 clusters
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fsck -V -C /dev/sda1
fsck from util-linux 2.37.2
[/usr/sbin/fsck.vfat (1) -- /dev/sda1] fsck.vfat /dev/sda1 
fsck.fat 4.2 (2021-01-31)
/dev/sda1: 26 files, 5341/130812 clusters
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fsck -V -C /dev/sda2
fsck from util-linux 2.37.2
[/usr/sbin/fsck.ext4 (1) -- /dev/sda2] fsck.ext4 -C0 /dev/sda2 
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
/dev/sda2: clean, 208346/15597568 files, 3963251/62383360 blocks

EDIT 2
Changed SSD but after reinstalling 24.04 with kernel 6.8.0-45 and then rolling back to last state before the bootup crash, I got the same boot failure and for same cause.
** So it is not disk damage. **
Ideally I would like to get the new 24.04 kernel 6.8.0-45 and then reimport all my application prpgrams and config files, etc. But I am not sure if Timeshift allows this manoeuvre.
EDIT 3
This is all a consequence of Ubuntu 24.04 having a bug in it that prevented it working properly after it was installed as an update to 22.04.4 LTS. As soon as a kernel update is done the bug kicks in.
No cure like system restoring is possible. So it's a case of a fresh install of Ubuntu 24.04 to a cleaned SSD drive and then use a backup tool like BackInTime with your backup drive to restore data files.

You need to run fsck on umounted partition(s). Or use live installer, or boot using recovery mode before you mount partitions. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1474846/fixing-bad-superblock-on-ssd-drive-is-e2fsck-safe-to-run

Had the exact same issue with 6.8.0-45 on my old Lenovo. Switching back to 6.8.0-44 solved it.

I had something similar yesterday due to a failed kernel update to -45.
I clicked the hard reset button (physical button on my computer)
So, on the next boot I was able to select in grub menu the kernel to start with. I've chosen the previous kernel (6.8.0-44). Then it started fine.
I ran sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade and noticed from the errors that, I had some old software from 20.04 still residing on my PC conflicting with the kernel.
In my case I had to remove 2 versions of akvcam to allow the configuration of the new kernel. Link for removal instructions which allowed me to go forward and fix it all with sudo apt upgrade
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68261311
Quote from the link:

To remove the module, you need to run sudo dkms remove modul/version --all to prevent it from being rebuilt during the next update, you must also remove the sources under /usr/src/.


here is an example of how to remove akvcam module

dkms status


akvcam, 1.2.0, 5.12.14-arch1-1, x86_64: installed

sudo dkms remove akvcam/1.2.0 --all
sudo rm -rf /usr/src/akvcam-1.2.0/
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/akvcam.conf
good luck marco manngatter


I tried this earlier when the boot-up menu offered older kernels. But I had the same issue with 6.8.0-41.
