My Ubuntu cannot boot after hard shut down
I have a problem with my Ubuntu. I have Acer laptop that has 1tb hdd default with win 10. And i upgrade it by add nvme SSD and install Ubuntu in SSD. My laptop run dual boot os, like usual there is Grub when I start the laptop.
There is no problem even after a year, but yesterday my Ubuntu freeze when I open Firefox. And I decide to hard shut down the laptop by pressing the power button. After a couple minute I turn on the laptop, but there is no Grub, the laptop just instantly boot to Windows.
I try to restart but again but still no Grub showing. Even in bios there is no Ubuntu option. I remove the HDD where the windows 10 installed so teoritically my laptop only have 1 option to boot, my SSD. But my laptop say "there is no bootable device". Is my laptop cannot read my SSD? So I install the HDD again and boom the Grub is showing, and I choose Ubuntu like usual.
But there is a longggg loading in Acer and Ubuntu logo, after a couple minutes there is "initramfs" Bash showing. I don't know what it is so I run "exit" command but nothing happen.
I try to run Ubuntu in USB, select the Try Ubuntu, and see the disk manager. I found the HDD and USB but not my SSD. Is there a way to fix it? If i cant boot to my Ubuntu I just want to copy my data in that OS
More information when I boot windows and open disk manager, my SSD showing, but I cant see my data inside.

You've tagged you're using Ubuntu 23.04 from 2023-April; is that correct?

Ubuntu 23.04 (along with all flavors) is End-of-Life and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/01/26/ubuntu-23-04-lunar-lobster-reached-end-of-life-on-january-25-2024/   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

After hard shutdown, files may be corrupted & fsck then required.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilesystemTroubleshooting & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1474846/fixing-bad-superblock-on-ssd-drive-is-e2fsck-safe-to-run & http://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789

is there a different solution or steps for different version?

Performing file-system checks are specific to your file-system and not the release of Ubuntu...   Different methods exist for ext, btrfs, xfs, zfs etc.

Alright I use Ext, today I install the SSD to another laptop that use Pop!_OS. And in the file manager I can access the data from my Ubuntu. I think I will format the SSD after backup my data. Thanks!
